# GetAsyncKeyState and Numpad numbers [C++]

Tags: c++

How would you detect a numpad number keypress? I know this is a stupid question, but I just started recently getting into programming a few days ago and working my way into C/C# and C++.

Here's what I have so far:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0) {
    // do this
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to learn C, C# *and* C++ at the same time? It's like learning Swedish, Danish and Norwegian all att the same time.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Nope. I'm doing C and C++ first. :/

Comment: I still suggest you learn one language at a time. While C and C++ are similar, they are still *very* different languages.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Okay. Will keep that noted. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own question. The code above does work. I just forgot to close the main with another bracket. Silly mistake. Sorry!